# PROLOG program semantic and exercise

Tags: prolog, logic

First of all I have a doubt about the semantic of a program , for example :

```
length([],0).
length([_|L],N):-
    length(L,N0),
    N is N0 + 1.
```

The first instruction means the base case , or it has other meanings ?

I have to write a prolog program that, given a number, returns a list of numbers from 0 to the given number. 
For example, when the input is 5, the output is [0,1,2,3,4,5].

I'm looking for a solution of this problem but I do not know how to start.

Comment: Yes, the first rule is the base case. What have you tried for generating the list of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a predicate in SWI-Prologs library that does almost what you need to do. It is called `numlist/3`. You can use it with lower and upper boundary:

```
?- numlist(1, 5, L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

And [here the implementation](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/576555c233e6b30c52bcb5254a498f40d23b2e54/library/lists.pl#L585-L603):

```
numlist(L, U, Ns) :-
    must_be(integer, L),
    must_be(integer, U),
    L =< U,
    numlist_(L, U, Ns).

numlist_(U, U, List) :-
    !,
    List = [U].
numlist_(L, U, [L|Ns]) :-
    L2 is L+1,
    numlist_(L2, U, Ns).
```

You can get rid of the upper half of this completely, and lose one argument (your Lower is just 1).

If you play with this a bit you should be able to figure it out.